# JSON: Error when converting to dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm having problems converting JSON to dictionary, can anyone help?

> 04:33:25 - Error while loading config. System.InvalidCastException:
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'. 
>   at Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.ToFlatDictionary(JToken
>   token, String path) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   28    at
>   Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.<>c.b__0_0(JProperty
>   x) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   19    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)    at
>   Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.ToFlatDictionary(JToken token,
>   String path) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   18    at
>   Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.<>c.b__0_0(JProperty
>   x) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   19    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)    at
>   Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.ToFlatDictionary(JToken token,
>   String path) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   18    at
>   Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.<>c.b__0_0(JProperty
>   x) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   19    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)    at
>   Seegal.Core.Extentions.JsonExtensions.ToFlatDictionary(JToken token,
>   String path) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Extentions\JsonExtentions.cs:line
>   18    at Seegal.Core.Config.ConfigHandler.Load(String apiUrl) in
>   C:\Users\admin\workspace\Seegal\Seegal\Seegal\Core\Config\ConfigHandler.cs:line
>   49

The JSON I'm converting to a dictionary:

```
{
    "bingo": {
        "ftp" : {
            "host" : "",
            "port" : 21,
            "username" : "",
            "password" : "",
            "enabled" : 0,
        }
    },

    "snowman": {
        "sockets" : {
            "host" : "127.0.0.1",
            "port" : 2000,
        }
    }
}
```

The method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToFlatDictionary(this JToken token, string path = null)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                return token.Children<JProperty>()
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.ToFlatDictionary(x.Name))
                    .ToDictionary(x => path == null ? x.Key : string.Join(".", path, x.Key), x => x.Value);

            case JTokenType.Array:
                return token
                    .SelectMany((x, i) => x.ToFlatDictionary(i.ToString()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => path == null ? x.Key : string.Join(".", path, x.Key), x => x.Value);

            default:
                return new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [path] = (string)((JValue)token).Value
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Converting line, the line the error happens on:

```
_configElements = JObject.Parse(responseText).ToFlatDictionary();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be because it seems to be attempting to direct cast an int64 value into string. If you tweak the default statement as below the code should start working

```
            default:
                return new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [path] = (((JValue)token).Value).ToString()
                };
```

A safer alternative would be convert.ToString to guard against NULL,etc. but for the immediate issue at hand, not using type casting should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your default case makes an invalid assumption. That a value is neither an array nor an object does not imply that it has a conversion to string defined for its value.

Here is a working version

```
static Dictionary<string, string> ToFlatDictionary(this JToken token, string path = null)
{
    switch (token)
    {
        case JObject jo: return jo.Properties()
            .SelectMany(x => x.Value.ToFlatDictionary(x.Name))
            .ToDictionary(x => path == null ? x.Key : $"{path}.{x.Key}", x => x.Value);

        case JArray ja: return ja
            .SelectMany((x, i) => x.ToFlatDictionary(i.ToString()))
            .ToDictionary(x => path == null ? x.Key : $"{path}.{x.Key}", x => x.Value);

        case var v when v != null: return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            [path] = v.Value<string>()
        };

        default: return new Dictionary<string, string> { };
    }
}
```